# install rvm rails - unmet dependencies libffi-dev depends libffi6 - Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, installation, rvm

Installing rvm rails on Ubuntu 14.04.4:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Output shows:

```
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
```

finally errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libffi-dev : Depends: libffi6 (= 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12) but 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Doesnt fix.

My /etc/apt/sources.list looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main multiverse universe restricted
```

From what i have searched, I need to download the `3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12ubuntu0.1` package and install it manually? If this is the case how would I do this?

Also I'd like to understand why this package is not at the latest version - maybe a dumb question but I don't understand what could be the cause?

Installing these packages using apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libffi6
libffi6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libffi-dev : Depends: libffi6 (= 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12) but 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: try calling `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` first

Comment: @UriAgassi have tried to install libffi6 and libffi-dev to no avail. I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using aptitude and selecting the non-default option to downgrade the libffi6 package to allow libffi-dev to be installed:

```
sudo aptitude install libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

try to install libffi6.

> apt-get install libffi6

if it doesn't work try it like this:

add `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Then:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt-get install libffi6
```